# EKS HPA scale down on newer node first

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, hpa

How do I make sure the eks scale down the newly created pod first?

So what is happening in my case I have 4 node initially.During scaling up, the pod is scaled on newly created node(since insufficient cpu/memory on initial node) which is normal (now the node became 5 node). But when scaling down is happening the HPA remove the pod in initial node first (instead removing from newer node) causing I have extra node which is 5(which cause extra money). How can I make sure the HPA scale down the pod in newer node first?

Example:
initial pod - 4
HPA scaling up to - 8 (when peak use)
HPA scaling down to 4 again (became normal)

I want the 4 initial pod in initial node be exactly where they are after HPA scaling down

Comment: [HPA + Cluster Autoscaler not being cost efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774581/hpa-cluster-autoscaler-not-being-cost-efficient) asks a similar question (but doesn't really have an answer).  You don't get a choice over _which_ Pod will get deleted when HPA scales in; the behavior I'd expect to see is that the cluster autoscaler would try to repack Pods so they'd fit, but it definitely does not target exactly 100% utilization.

Comment: Have a look a Karpenter's consolidation feature, https://karpenter.sh/preview/concepts/deprovisioning/#consolidation